# Cannot connect to my MySQL server from Webserver

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2012-r2

I created a mysql server on Windows Server 2012. Locally I can connect to it using `root` and I imported a db called `foo` which I can see and manipulate via MySQL workbench. I now created an apache server on another Windows Server 2012 machine and installed Apache and php which works fine.

I uploaded a php website to the Apache server and it pulls information the db `foo` however it is not connecting. When I create a php file to test the connection I am getting a `500 error`. What could be causing this issue? Please note on my MySQL server the firewall is disabled and I only have the root user created.

Comment: Please read the MySQL documentation. Giving permissions to other hosts is [extensively documented](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privilege-system.html). In short, you need to create a MySQL user with the appropriate permissions on the db `foo` and allow the access from the web server.

Comment: added a user and still getting a 500 error.

Comment: Then read the log files to get the specific error reason.

Comment: ok now got something to work with I am getting the error Connection failed: could not find driver. I am using PDO to test the db connect however in my php.ini I already have extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll and extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll enabled. Am I missing any other extension for php on my webserver